# Solr Collection Creation and Custom Collection Libraries

Tags: solr

I've run into a situation where we sometimes have to completely wipe an index and then re-index a collection. This process of course takes a lot of time. I don't want to allow for any or at least extended downtime in Prod. Thus, I am researching into a way in Solr to create a new Collection that is a copy of an old collection, but without the data. I can re-index this new Collection with little or any service degradation. I then want to use aliases to point the new Collection to the alias that our clients are using so that they will start using the new Collection without even knowing it.

I'm currently running 4.2, but wondering if I shouldn't upgrade to 4.7 in order to support this better. Seems like 4.2 has most of the same Collection API support.

One of the first snags I'm hitting is that the Collection I am copying has a lib folder in it with customer libraries. If possible I want to push these out to the solrhome/lib folder so that they only get loaded once. My problem with this is that if I have different versions of say a custom data importer, then I will run into classloader issues.

Has anyone successfully implemented this kind of scenario and could provide some insight into the pitfalls and successes that you had and what worked for you?

More Details...
I have many different collections that are part of this Solr cloud. I don't want to effect any of the other collections if possible while making changes to the new copied collection.

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to first wipe out your index? Do you have unique key in your schema?

Comment: you can always write a script for that.

Comment: There are rare cases when we change the schema and the index retains the information in the old format. For example if you delete a field or rename a field in your schema it can cause the index to be in an inconsistent state. This especially seems to happen when using atomic updates. This means that you don't always wipe out the bad data during an update. Otherwise, we would just do a full import of the data in Prod and replace indexes on the fly.

Comment: Writing scripts is the way that I am trying to go about it, but the question is what is the content of that script? What is the flow/process to accomplish this? There are scripts to update zookeeper with new Solr config, create/delete a collection, create aliases, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also having a similar kind of situation where I might to modify solr schema and need to re index the whole data. But I don't have much downtime in production. So, we came up with a solution like..

Let's say I have a SolrCloud1 (existing one), with collection1 (It has it's own structure). I have my application running in different machine. There is a load-balancer in between my SolrCloud1 and application.

Now, create a separate SolrCloud (say, SolrCloud2) with collection1. Maintain the same structure as it was previously. Now, do the re indexing part in this SolrCloud2. When it's done, make available the new SolrCloud under the load-balancer. When the new SolrCLoud2 is up, shut down the SolrCloud1.

Thus without any production down time you'll re index the data. Users won't be able to know anything about this. Hope this will help.

Comment: That is a viable solution, but might not be the best solution for our situation. In our case we have many different collections and keeping a copy of the whole cloud would mean that we would also have to keep a copy or re-index the data for every other collection as well as the one in question. Let me add some more of these details to the main question so as to help clarify our scenario.